# New Created Site can't be Visible on Survey Force.com

Tags: apex, permission-sets, survey, salesforce-survey

Dear All Salesforce Expert,

I've an Issue regarding the Sites that have been created but the Sites can't be visible on the Selected Site on Survey force. com. The following are the screen capture of the configuration that I've done to do:

[image: New Sites Created]

[image: The Created Sites can't be Visible on the Selected Site]

are there any Missed configuration from me related this need? kindly advise and need the answer in ASAP

Thank you so much,
Ery Eryanto

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been resolved with an update to the package:

> This is because of Enhanced Domains. If you have deployed enhanced domain
> on that org then the old code doesn't work.
>
> I have made a change. This works with or without enhanced domains. I have
> also published this change on APpExchange in latest version.
>
> Change is in
> https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/survey-force/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/ViewShareSurveyComponentController.cls
>
> Change is at line #59 and #75. You can manually change the code in that
> class and it will work.

See https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/survey-force/issues/152